# Force button click based on a specific event

Tags: javascript

Sorry if my question I won't include too much code but I am new with Javascript.
I need to create a script that will take the value from this HTML code:

```
<span class="bianco" id="contatore_139287">91.5</span>
```

If the value is lower than 0.9 the javascript function should force the click of the following button:

```
<input type="button" value="PUNTA" onclick="puntal7h5n6o1ut5ovslhtou7ii2gu6(139287);" id="bottone2139287">
```

It will be installed on my browser to automate the process of clicking a button on my own website when that specific event happens ( value is lower than 0.9 as explained above )

Could you help?

Comment: How is the value in the span being generated?

Comment: I don't believe this can work, a click on a button has to be user initiated, not programmatic. You could, though, check the value and then call the function (or whatever purge action you want) programmatically.

Comment: You can click a button with javascript, no problem.

Comment: I phrased it badly, but it depends, so far as I understand it, on what the button, link or whatever does.

Comment: Take a look at this example, http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/zTwaU/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how it can be done

**HTML**

```
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<span id="watch">0.0</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */
/*global */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof window.MutationObserver !== "function") {
        window.MutationObserver = window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
    }

    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var watch = document.getElementById("watch");
    var i = 87;
    var stop = 95;
    var detect = 91.5;
    var step = 0.5;
    var id;

    function click(obj) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");

        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

        return obj.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    function whenClicked() {
        alert("I've been clicked!");
    }

    button.addEventListener("click", whenClicked, false);

    if (typeof window.MutationObserver !== "function") {
        watch.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function () {
            if (parseFloat(watch.textContent) === detect) {
                click(button);
            }
        }, false);
    } else {
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.target.id === "watch" && parseFloat(mutation.target.textContent) === detect) {
                    click(button);
                }
            });
        });

        observer.observe(document, {
            childList: true,
            characterData: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    }

    id = setInterval(function () {
        i += step;
        if (i > stop) {
            clearInterval(id);
            
            if (typeof window.MutationObserver !== "function") {
                watch.removeEventListener("DOMNodeInserted");
            } else {
                observer.disconnect();
            }
            
            return;
        }

        watch.textContent = i;
    }, 1000);
}());
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/tq9gE/)

Of course you don't need to programmatically click the button, just execute the buttons's function when it reaches the criteria you want.